# Why Do I Not Receive Emails Sent using the Azure DevOps API?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I am able to POST to the SendMail endpoint (POST [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/sendmail?api-version=7.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/wit/sendmail?api-version=7.0)) and I get a 204 response (Success. No Content Returned) but never receive the email. I've checked to see if the email was filtered out by our spam filter and it wasn't. The recipient I am sending to is a user in our ADO subscription.

Has anyone had any success using this API endpoint? I cannot use the ADO template notifications because I need to customize the content of the email. This is an email that needs to be sent from a pipeline, BTW.

The body of my POSTs look like this (except that the email address is a valid email address associated with a user of our ADO subscription):

```
{
    "message": {
        "subject": "This is a test of the Azure DevOps SendMail REST Endpoint",
        "body" : "Was this email received?",
        "cc" : {
            "tfsIds" : [],
            "emailAddresses": [],
            "unresolvedEntityIds" : []       
        },
        "inReplyTo": "",
        "to" : {
            "tfsIds" : [],
            "emailAddresses": [test@fakedomain.com],
            "unresolvedEntityIds" : []
        },
        "replyTo" : {
            "tfsIds" : [],
            "emailAddresses": [test@fakedomain.com],
            "unresolvedEntityIds" : []
        }
    }
}
```

The endpoint doc page is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/send-mail/send-mail?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0

Comment: Does it work if you send to different recipients, like a Gmail account, as a test?

Comment: @ceejayoz I've tried sending to another user who also is a registered user of our ADO subscription and that also didn't work.

Comment: Try sending to something that is *not* your ADO subscription.   GMail can be very picky, so if you have a vanity domain on web hosting or some other less suspicious mail server that's a better test.

Comment: @Dave S Nothing suspicious about the email domain. It is a government domain and it is being sent to someone else in the organization.

Comment: Suspicious can mean does not properly handle SPF, DKIM not just being suspected spam.  The mail server sending the mail must validate itself as being allowed to send mail from the domain.

Comment: @Emmanuel The point is to isolate the problem. If you send to a Gmail account, and it works, that's useful information.

Answer (score 1):

In the example, you didn't wrap the email addresses with double quotes